# Install OpenNTF-Domino-API-2.0.0 to the Designer Client

Tags: osgi, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I downloaded the zip OpenNTF-Domino-API-2.0.0 locally and unzipped it. According to the documentation that I have been able to find there should be two updatesite databases --one for the server and one for the designer, but they do not appear to be in the download.
[image]

I unzipped the UpdateSite file and get a site.xml file and was able to add that to my updatesite.nsf on my server. But I do not see how to update the designer. All of the documentation/demos that I have found refer to an update-Designer.nsf . 
How do you install it to the designer client??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps in this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/OliverBusse/utilizing-the-openntf-domino-api. The steps to install in Domino Designer are on slide 16 and added here for future reference:

- Open DDE‘s preferences

  - Goto „Domino Designer“ section
  - Activate „Enable Eclipse plug-in install“
- Open the update site NSF you just created

  - Goto „Actions, Show URLs“
  - Copy one of the two URLs to clipboard
- Goto „File, Application, Install“

  - Choose „Search for new features to install“
  - On the next screen „Add (a) Remote Location“
  - Enter a name for it and paste the URL in the clipboard
  - On the next screen check the ODA entry and click next/yes if you are asked to

Comment: To expand on the "two update sites" part: that indeed used to be the case, but o switched in recent builds to generating a single site that works in both. The previous way was an annoying side effect of our earlier build process.